# Python: Search list and give boolean

Tags: python, list, search, boolean

If I have a list like so:
`List = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e',]`
what is the simplest way to get a Boolean answer if, I for instance asked it if `'g'` was inside this list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
l = ['a','b','c','d']
if 'g' in l:
    print True
```

Answer (score 8):

```
print 'g' in ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

def inlist (lst, character):
    if character in lst and type(lst) is list:
        return True
    else:
        return False

print inlist(List, 'g')
```

As you expect, this prints: `False`

NOTE: try to name your lists other than `List`, as that can cause some confusion when reading.

Comment: @user2852955: if this was helpful to you, then please consider it for acceptance. :)

Comment: I'm curious why you think a function is better here

Comment: @gnibbler: for reusability. It's much easier to deal with than having to rewrite the check every single time you want to check if a character is in some list.

Comment: How? You're just replacing the infix function with a postfix function, and naming it to make it look like it only works for lists when it really would work equally well for any type of sequence.

Comment: @gnibbler: correct on all accounts. I researched your comments, realized my error, and fixed it accordingly. Thank you.